Api is not responsding in react native cli but working on postman
it is taking forever to validate the token, but the api seems to work very well in postman and also in ios emulator, the problem is occuring only in my android device.
my axios response
Starting Request {"adapter": ["xhr", "http", "fetch"], "data": {"AccessToken": "access token", "RefreshToken": "refresh token"}, "env": {"Blob": [Function Blob], "FormData": [Function FormData]}, "headers": {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"}, "maxBodyLength": -1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "put", "timeout": 20000, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "transitional": {"clarifyTimeoutError": false, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "silentJSONParsing": true}, "url": "https://some-name.ngrok-free.app/appName-service/oauth/token/validate", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}

below is how iam validating the token
const validateUserToken = async () => {
    try {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('pathbeatUserData');
        if (!token) {
            return { error: 'Token not found' };
        }
        let parsedToken = JSON.parse(token);
        parsedToken = parsedToken.Token as TokenType;

        const response = await axios.put<any>(
            baseUrl + '/appName/oauth/token/validate',
            parsedToken,
            {
                timeout: 20000, // Timeout after 20 seconds
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',

                },
            }
        );

        return { data: response.data };
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(error)
        return { error: error.message ? error.message : 'An unexpected error occurred' };
    }
};

below is the android manifest file
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

I am expecting what really is the cause and how can i fix it.

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5366
Visit this page where they talk about this. The code provided appears to be working well, but I'm not sure in what situation you are experiencing this error.
